# cannot import jsonarray into jsp in eclipse

Tags: java, json, jsp

I want to use JSONArray in jsp.  I have imported the library like this

> 

I also downloaded the java-json jar and paste into WEB-INF lib, please see the snapshot of my windows.

```
<%@ page import="java.utii.List" %> 
<%@ page import org.json.JSONArray %> 
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<% 
List<String> exampleList = new ArrayList<>();
exampleList.add("Apple");
exampleList.add("Orange");
exampleList.add("Lemon");
JSONArray fruitList = new JSONArray();
fruitList.addAll(exampleList);
%>
```

[snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpUqk.png)
[snapshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AKXt.png)

but the compiler still complains that Jsonarray cannot be resolved to a type.  What could be wrong?  Thank you.

Comment: do not put java code into jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you wrote:

```
<%@ page import org.json.JSONArray %>
```

But you should have written:

```
<%@ page import="org.json.JSONArray" %>
```

Answer (score -3):

you should check eclipse settings,make sure this lib already in classpath.